# Generics List<String> and List<Integer> not behaving as expected

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

Why is the `println` printing "tom" and not showing any runtime exception after casting to `List<Integer>`, while it is not able to print the value 1 after casting to `List<String>`?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List list = Arrays.asList(1, "tom");

        System.out.println(((List<Integer>) list).get(1));
        // "tom"

        System.out.println(((List<String>) list).get(0));
        // ClassCastException: Integer cannot be cast to String
    }
}
```

Comment: It *is* showing runtime exception.

Comment: comment out one type of list at a time to get the desired output i.e. // List<String> list3 = list1;
// System.out.println(list3.get(0));

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first call of `println` is statically dispatched to `PrintStream.println(Object)` and the second call is dispatched to `PrintStream.println(String)`. So for the second call the compiler puts an implicit cast to `String` which then fails with `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this, bcoz what i think in first case it shud go to PrintStream.println(Integer) if it goes PrintStream.println(String) for the second case or both shud have PrintStream.println(Object).

Comment: There is no `PrintStream.println(Integer)`. The compiler always dispatches to a method with the most specific signature. The most specific type for `Integer` is `Object`, and the most specific type for `String` is `String`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the java compiler picks methods at compile time, not runtime.
And at compile time it will pick the method [`PrintStream.print(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29), not [`PrintStream.print(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28int%29) or [`PrintStream.print(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.Object%29), both of which would succeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer i = new Integer(101);
String s = new String(i); // undefined and Invalid
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(i); // defined and Valid

String s2 = "tom";
Integer i2 = new Integer(s2); //defined and valid
```

So when you assign a non generic list to a generic one it is assigned but when you are printing it it checks for type safety or define constructors for casting if there are valid and defined constructors then it is printed else shows class cast exception as the class can not be casted due to lack of undefined constructors for casting.

If I am wrong please help me out with the correct logic...

Comment: This has nothing to do with constructors.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem can be avoided by using generics and is the primary motivation for using generics.

This is the actual flow of your code, from your second `println(`) point of view:

1. your code declares an `ArrayList` of type `Object`;
2. It adds an `Integer` and a `String` to the `ArrayList`.
3. It cast your list to a `String` list. Your list is marked as being restricted to `String`.

Java generics are a compile-time feature only so your list can accepts without any problem `String` and `Integer` elements. The object itself knows nothing about what types it's supossed to contain unlike to the compiler.

3. It attemps to retreive the first element of your casted list which is supposed to be a `String` and cast it to `String` implicitly.
4. Calls `println(String x)` from `PrintStream` class.

But this first element is actually not a `String` and is an `Integer`.
You cannot cast an `Integer` to a `String`.

Read [Generics in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) motivation section example.